# Two Apache tomcat server's situation

Tags: apache, web-services, web-applications, tomcat7, web-deployment

Consider a some server having two tomcat server. Two server having two different web applications.

1st - Primary Application(server-IP:8080)
Location on server - server-IP\Primary\Apache-Tomcat-7\webapps\launchPrimary
2nd - Secondary Application(server-IP:8089/)
Location on server - server-IP\secondary\Apache-Tomcat-7\webapps\launchSeondary

At one point, clicking the link in Primary Web Application will open the secondary Application. Now need to access one folder in 
server-IP\Primary\Apache-Tomcat-7\webapps\launchPrimary

SIMPLE: I want to access a file/folder in server-IP\Primary\Apache-Tomcat-7\webapps\launchPrimary\accessthisfolder from a file(html) in server-IP\secondary\Apache-Tomcat-7\webapps\launchSeondary

Any suggestions without moving the secondary webapp to primary ?

Comment: define _access one folder_

Comment: that one folder is "scripts" basically have js files.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts are consumed by a web browser, so if webapp1 serves an HTML page that has reference to scripts from webapp2 (like  `<script src="http://ip:port/webapp2/myscripts.js"></script>`) it's going to work fine for scenario from your comment.

Comment: Oleg, this doesn't seem to work. Any other work around ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492876/how-to-access-files-between-two-different-ports-in-apache-webaap